# Website displaying improperly on only one computer

Tags: html, css

So I put up a website rangaire.herokuapp.com, and it displays properly on every computer I have tested it on but one.  The screen resolution is 1920 x 1080.  It makes the div:after attribute infringe on the above text.  I have cleared cache and history, just not sure what else to do.  Any ideas?

Browser is Win7 IE11

[image: The Problem]

this is the css.

```
.mfg {
    margin-top:19px;
    height: 4px;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    border-top: 6px solid #1D2148;
    color: #1D2148;
    text-align: center;

}
.mfg::after {
    content: "MFG";
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative; 
    top: -0.7em;  
    font-size: 2.2em;
    padding: 0 0.14em 0 .2em;
    background: white;
    color: #1D2148;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    margin-right: .1em;
    font-weight: 100;
}
```

Comment: Technically the letters MFG are actual content and so should not be used in a pseudo-element. Regardless, we need to see the HTML.CSS in JSfiddle. We don't have enough information at the moment although I don't like the negative margins and positioning I'm seeing.

Comment: The title reminds me of a joke with a doctor and a broken finger. Isn't *the computer* broken?

Comment: Always have to ask if compatibility mode is turned on. Also, make sure the ie is set to use the same browser/rendering engine versions as the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the particular browser having a larger text size. Check View -> Text size to make sure.

The problem is that some measurements are done in `em` while others are in `px`. This will cause mismatches when the user's default font size is not exactly `16px`.

The div with class `mfg` has

```
margin-top: 19px;
```

and its `::after` pseudo-element has

```
top: -0.7em;
font-size: 2.2em;
```

which means that with a root font size of 16px, the top of the text will at a relative position of 19 - 0.7 * 2.2 * 16 = about 6 pixels. But if you make the base font size 25% bigger, or 20px, the relative position becomes 19 - 0.7 * 2.2 * 20 = about 12 pixels, twice as large the distance.

Solution: Don't assume that `100%` means `16px`. Wherever you use `em` for a length unit, make sure you know what the font size really is. (That is, set the font size of `html` to a size in pixels.) Or, use `em` for everything throughout the CSS, instead of `px`.

Comment: Thats a great explanation.  Im about to implement that.  I normally use px, but was "testing" em to see which I liked more.